# What is new about this patent US3695017?

Tags: bicycles, us3695017

According to this, a dual bearing nut for a pedal has already been done: http://www.bikemag.com/blog/tested-momentum-bicycle-flypaper-pedals/

I need to study about patent no US3695017

Answer (score 1):

That patent was submitted in 1969, issued in 1970 and would have expired in 1987. In patenting the idea must be "new" as of the date of filing.